# Let $W$ be a subspace of a vector space $V$ .Show that $W \subseteq \textbf{v} + W \Rightarrow \textbf{v} + W \subseteq W.$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, quotient-spaces

> Show that $W \subseteq 
>  \textbf{v} + W \Rightarrow \textbf{v} + W \subseteq W.$

Guys, i have edited my original solution in the link below. Now here is my proof for the converse. Main thing is, is my proof now ok? Although i did not start straight away with let $x \in v+W$, then show $x \in W$, but i felt that my first part is necessary.

Note that for any $ \mathbf{w} \in W$ , we have $\mathbf{w} \in \mathbf{v} + W$ as well. 
Then
    $$ \mathbf{w} = \mathbf{v} + \mathbf{w}_{1} ~\text{for some } \mathbf{w_1} \in W ~~~ \implies ~~~ \mathbf{v} = \mathbf{w} - \mathbf{w}_{1} \in W$$
Let 
    $$ \mathbf{x} \in \mathbf{v} + W, ~~\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{v} + \mathbf{w}_{2} = \mathbf{w} - \mathbf{w}_{1} + \mathbf{w}_{2} \in W$$
Thus, $\mathbf{v} + W \subseteq W$.

[Let $W$ be a subspace of a vector space $V$ . Show that the following are equivalent.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2445874/let-w-be-a-subspace-of-a-vector-space-v-show-that-the-following-are-equiva/2445885#2445885)

Comment: yes it is correct. The "note that" is just a bit confusing as it seems that what follows has to be deduced while it is your assumption.

Answer (score 0):

It seems correct, but more complicated than needed.

Suppose $W\subseteq\mathbf{v}+W$. Then $\mathbf{0}=\mathbf{v}+\mathbf{w}$, for some $\mathbf{w}\in W$. Therefore
$$
\mathbf{v}=-\mathbf{w}\in W
$$
and so $\mathbf{v}+W\subseteq W$.